# JavaScript: How to get value of variable by name

Tags: javascript

I have JS file with:

```
var text1 = "There is text1";
var text2 = "There is text2";
var text3 = "There is text3";
```

And in variable actual_text i have "text2" in str.

```
actual_text = "text2";
```

It is in string because it is based on the previous code, which is correct.

Now I need to retype "text2" in actual_text to text2 (as variable with content) and using variable actual_text put it to output:

```
<p id="myoutput"></p>
document.getElementById('myoutput').innerHTML=actual_text;
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: `eval` may help here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval But, be careful! `eval` is a very very very very very very very very very very dangerous function!

Comment: Sounds like an array might be helpful. But we need more context to be certain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var text1 = "There is text1";
var text2 = "There is text2";
var text3 = "There is text3";

actual_text = "text2";

document.getElementById('myoutput').innerHTML = this[actual_text];
```

```html
<p id="myoutput"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

use textContent instead of innerHTML

```
document.getElementById('myoutput').textContent = actual_text;
```

hope it works